# PostgressSql - Table formation

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table in below structure which is created using postgresql
**Category can have value of (Truck,Bus,Car and Bike)
Lane can have value of (Lane 1 and Lane 2)**
[image]

From this table structure i need to display as below in the dashboard

[image]

I am new to DB side can anyone help in fixing this?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cameralocation,lane, videoTime,
 sum(case when (category='bike') then vehicleavgspeed else 0 end) as "Bike-Speed",
 sum(case when (category='bike') then vehiclecount else 0 end) as "Bike-Count",
 sum(case when (category='commercial') then vehicleavgspeed else 0 end) as "commercial-Speed",
 sum(case when (category='commercial') then vehiclecount else 0 end) as "commercial-Count",
 sum(case when (category='car') then vehicleavgspeed else 0 end) as "car-Speed",
 sum(case when (category='car') then vehiclecount else 0 end) as "car-Count"
 FROM public.inferencedata where lane='${lane}' and inferenceid='${videoTime}'  group by cameralocation,lane,videoTime;
```